# Fixed position element inside fixed position element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm building an application and on mobile we have a panel that slides in and takes up 100% of the viewport. This is has the `position:fixed` attribute attached to it. At the top of the panel I have a "back to" link, which is a `<p>` with an anchor `<a>Back to...</a>` inside it.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to affix this to the top of the page so that when the user scrolls down the page the "back to" link is always at the top of the page. The reason for this is that the panels can often contain a lot of information, especially on mobile. I do not want to use Javascript as I'm hoping there is a way around this with CSS.

I've tried giving this `<p>` a `position:fixed` attribute but as it's containing block is positioned `fixed` it doesn't do anything! Is there a way around this issue? Has anyone done something similar before ?

HTML

```
<div id="panelDiv">
  <p><a href="#" class="back-to-link">Back to...</a></p>
  ......
  Panel content goes here
  ......
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myDiv {

  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0.85714em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 350ms ease-in 0s, opacity 350ms ease-in 0s;
   z-index: 9999;
}

p {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

Now, what I think is happening is that because the container is already fixed, the browser already keeps the container fixed to the top and therefore when I add the same to the containing element it doesn't do anything. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried making the `<p>` a sibling instead of a child of the panel?

Comment: If they are both going to scroll with the page together, then the paragraph doesn't need a position of fixed. Perhaps an absolute or simply leaving it static?

Comment: @AdamWhitney I've tried giving it position absolute but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Okay, well how about this: `<div id="panelDiv"><div style="position: relative"><p><a href="#" class="back-to-link">Back to...</a></p>......Panel content goes here......</div></div>`    - So basically you have a div with position _relative_ inside of the fixed positioned one.

Comment: @j08691 how do you mean?

Comment: @AdamWhitneyjust tried this but it doesn't work! Thanks though, I'm still investigating...